# LTspice Transient Analysis: Different parameters at different time points

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to model a memristor using LTspice using the following subcircuit code.

```
* Knowm Mean Metastable Switch Memristor SPICE Model

* Copyright Tim Molter Knowm Inc. 2017

* Connections:
* TE:  Top electrode
* BE:  Bottom electrode
* XSV: External connection to plot state variable
*      that is not used otherwise

.SUBCKT MEM_KNOWM TE BE XSV

* Ron:  Minimum device resistance
* Roff: Maximum device resistance
* Von:  Threshold voltage to turn device on
* Voff: Threshold voltage to turn device off
* TAU:  Time constant
* T:    Temperature
    
.params Ron=4e5 Roff=3e10 Voff=1 Von= 1 TAU=0.0000000001 T=298.5 x0=0

* Function G(V(t)) - Describes the device threshold
.func G(V) = V/Ron+(1-V)/Roff

* Function Gauss
* gc(a,b){(a+a*gauss(b/3))}
   
* Function F(V(t),x(t)) - Describes the SV motion
.func F(V1,V2) = (1/TAU)*((    1/(1+exp(-1/(T*boltz/echarge)*(V1- Von)))   )*(1-V2)-(    1-(1/(1+exp(-1/(T*boltz/echarge)*(V1+Voff))))    )*V2

* Memristor I-V Relationship
.func IVRel(V1,V2) = V1*G(V2)

* Circuit to determine state variable
* dx/dt = F(V(t),x(t))*G(V(t))
Cx XSV 0 {1}
.ic V(XSV) = x0
Gx 0 XSV value={F(V(TE,BE),V(XSV,0))}

* Current source for memristor IV response
Gmem TE BE value={IVRel(V(TE,BE),V(XSV,0))}

.ENDS MEM_KNOWM
```

I would like Von to be a stochastic parameter and I was able to implement it using a Gaussian distribution so that for each different run, Von is indeed a different value. However, I would like the parameter to vary during one transient analysis at different time points.
I am aware that there is the option to use '.step param' to step through a model parameter, but in my understanding, it only works when you perform multiple analyses. I would like to do so but with specified time points in one analysis.
Does anyone have any tips? Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible to change the parameter value during the simulations using a command. But you might be able to realize it using some controlled switches. What do you want to change? Please provide an example.

Comment: I would like to change the threshold voltage of a transistor for each voltage sweep that I apply.

Comment: What if you put a voltage source in series with the gate and adjust it over time using PWL?

Comment: @user312677 That information needs to go in the question. However, I have to wonder about your goals if you need to do that -- no transistor I know changes its parameters like that. It sounds too much like an XY problem.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I am trying to model a memristor that has a stochastic threshold voltage. This stochasticity is pretty useful for neuromorphic computing.

Comment: @SteKulov That sounds like a really good idea. Could you elaborate on how you would implement this for a third-party model that doesn't exactly have a gate port or anything?

Comment: @user312677  It would likely depend on what the subcircuit is and does.  I heard "threshold voltage" & "transistor" and assumed a MOSFET, which would mean you add a voltage source in front of the gate such that it offsets \$V_{gs}\$ and changes the effective \$V_{th}\$ with respect to the voltage applied prior to the voltage source.  If you need something more specific, then we would need to see the subcircuit code you're trying to modify.

Comment: @user312677 That information needs to go into the question, too. As you can see, we're at a point where, with each comment, something new is revealed, which was not part of the OP. That's why I said it's an XY problem. If you want to model a memristor then there are models, and since they are behavioural in nature, you could modify the formulas to include a dynamic parameter (e.g. `time`-dependent).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for the tip! I have updated the OP. I do indeed need to somehow modify the formulas to include a time-dependent parameter, and I am wondering how I could do that.

Comment: @user312677 See, if you did that in the first place, I could have pointed you to the answer of your previous question, where I showed you two ways to add Gaussian noise: as a static `.param`, or as a dynamic signal. Either use that or implement your own `exp(-x^2)` as a `.func`. BTW, if that other answer does answer your question, you should use the check mark to select it. That tells future searches that the problem in the OP has a selected answer. It's all about posterity.